# Ant - XmlTask - Xpath predicate with xmlns

Tags: xml, xpath, ant

I have an xml file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>SomeApp</application>
        <default>true</default>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>AnotherApp</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>YetAnotherApp</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    ...
</Profile>
```

In an ant task I want to pick out any  elements that have default set to true, and change them to false. I can almost get there:

```
<target name="resetApps">
    <xmltask todir="stage/deploy/profiles/">           
        <fileset id="fileset" dir="stage/profiles/">
            <include name="**/*.profile"/>
        </fileset>
        <replace path="//*[local-name()='applicationVisibilities']/*[local-name()='default']/text()" withText="false"/>
    </xmltask>
</target>
```

(which just sets them *all* to false, regardless of the setting within)

Then I want to set "SomeApp" to default = true.

Again, I can almost get there if I don't have to specify local-name():

```
<replace path="/Profile/applicationVisibilities[application='SomeApp']/default/text()" withText="true"/>
```

So how do I combine the local-name() stuff with the predicate for pulling out "SomeApp"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ant, but given that it seems to be all about XML manipulation, I think it must provide a way to work with namespaces properly. Please look into how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `local-name()` criteria with `application='SomeApp'` criteria using simple `AND` operator :

```
//*[local-name()='applicationVisibilities' and application='SomeApp']/*[local-name()='default']/text()
```

**UPDATE :**

I missed to use `local-name()` filter for `application` node. The correct XPath should be as follow (formatted for readability) :

```
//*[
     local-name()='applicationVisibilities' 
        and 
     ./*[local-name()='application and .='SomeApp']
   ]
/*[local-name()='default']/text()
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either... I'm running it through http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Comment: @powlo tested using the same online tools, and worked for me. This is unformatted version of the XPath I used for testing : `//*[local-name()='applicationVisibilities' and ./*[local-name()='application' and .='SomeApp']]/*[local-name()='default']/text()`